# How to detect when networking initialized in /etc/init.d script on redhat 6

Tags: networking, redhat

I have an init.d script to start my process on boot and requires networking to be initialized. I can use utility nm-online which comes with NetworkManager package but problem will be at deployment where NW will be not installed so I have to have some other reliable option which can tell me network is set and I can connect to other server over network. I can keep trying till I get the networking up or connection is set but that will cause some other problem related to error reporting.

Here is the similar question asked for some other folk.

[How to detect when networking initialized in /etc/init.d script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478516/how-to-detect-when-networking-initialized-in-etc-init-d-script)

```
wait_for_network()
{
    [ -z "${LINKDELAY}" ] && LINKDELAY=10
    $INFO "Waiting for network..."
    if [ -f /usr/sbin/nm-online ]; then
        nm-online -q --timeout=$LINKDELAY || nm-online -q -x --timeout=30
    else
        check_for_network_up $LINKDELAY || check_for_network_up 30
    fi
    [ "$?" = "0" ] && success "network startup" || failure "network startup"
    echo
}
```

I was trying some other approach where I can check for route table. If network is not up, route command return zero entry but problem is I don’t know real number of route entry. It could be two on one machine where 10 on other machine.

```
check_for_network_up_old3() {
   let no_of_routes=`/bin/netstat -rn | wc -l`
   $INFO "netstat result $?"
   timeout=$1
   while [ "$timeout" != "0" ]; do
     let routes=`/sbin/ip route show | wc -l`
     $INFO "$routes"
     if [ $routes -gt 1 ]; then
        return 0
     fi
     timeout=$((timeout-1))
     sleep 1
     $INFO "check_for_network_up $timeout"
   done
  return 1
}
```